# Windows Authentication not working on my webserver

Tags: windows-authentication, iis-8.5

i have a weird thing going on. I have configured a website to use windows authentication. Now when i check on a client in a domain or on my domain controller i can access the website after entering my credentials. But on the webserver itself i can't login with these same credentials. Is this normal behaviour or what can cause this to happen ?

Comment: Learn about loop back check and you will see.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right way ;)